# override layout file 3rd party extension in magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.1.13

I want to override xml file of 3rd party extension in my custom theme in magento 2.1.13 . Till now i did following steps:-

1) path of the xml which i want to override is `app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/layoutfile.xml`
2) i had changed layout file and uploaded at `app/design/frontend/packageName/themename/Namespace_ModuleName/layout/layoutfile.xml`

after step 2. i had deleted `pub/static/*` and deployed static content again using `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` . Then i cleared and flushed cache. still my css has not been changed. please help me

Comment: do you want add CSS in above path ? Could you please share your xml code

Comment: no. i want to remove css file which has been included in the xml file

Comment: Could you please share your xml code

Comment: what i did is copyied complete xml file from module and removed css file name thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to remove CSS :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <remove src="name.css"/>
</head>
</page>
```

No need to copying full XML just put what you want to remove.

Comment: Welcome anytime :)